# Walking as a healthy habit for the aged and my doctor's thoughts on it

Tags: exercise, walking

Nowadays, many doctors recommend old people, who cannot do gym or such huge physical fitness exercises, to walk, as walking is considered and a clinically proven very good way to keep good health for the aged people.

Our doctor prescribes the same, but he is a bit different. According to him, walking only in the morning helps keeping good health. Walking in the evening has no good effect on the health of the person.

My question is, walking is a good physical exercise, but how does it matter if I walk in the morning or evening? Can anyone give a proper scientific explanation for what the doctor says? I cannot seem to find any, and neither can the doctor tell me anything satisfactory.

Comment: So you asked him and he wasn't able to explain why?  What did he actually say?  I know that there are some slightly different benefits depending on time of day, but regardless of the time walking is good for your health.  The ONLY minor thing I can think of is that people react differently to late evening/night exercise. For some people increases their energy levels and makes falling asleep harder. Others get tired after exercise and sleep better.  The elderly are more likely to suffer from sleep disturbances, so that's the only (rather thin) tie I can think of.

Comment: Can you develop a list of the potential benefits of walking, and then keep a log of your time of walk and observed results?

Comment: I rarely walk, that is,  I rarely get any time to walk. So, I'll never be able to get those benefits till retirement :-)

Comment: @DoctorWhom He said that his professor and books said so, and why they said so? That he didn't ask the professor or the books' authors. But I can assure you the books are not very good ones.

Comment: Well it's an odd thing for him to say, but there are a lot of misinformation sources out there, and a lot of theories that aren't proven one way or another.  But yes, walking is good, period.  As for the "benefits of walking" and having to wait until retirement, one of the key parts of exercise is PREVENTING chronic disease development or progression. Actually you can even reverse or lessen the diseases and/or their consequences on your body by exercise and what you eat.  The earlier you start, the better.  It's better to prevent a heart attack than recover from one.

Comment: @DoctorWhom yes, that is quite true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a physical therapist (PT) - considering we specialize in the application of movement and exercise.

Consistency NOT time of day is the key to any exercise regimen.

A walk in the park at 6AM or 2PM would have the same effects on "health".

Ask him explain to explain the reasoning behind this - and - if he'd send or write down the the name of the research article(s).

I'd gladly review it for you.

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry just saw you said he has no research backing this claim.

> I can tell you if you prefer to walk in the evening this is just as
>   beneficial as walking in the morning.  You will see the same health
>   benefits.

Walking is a fantastic exercise, so do it ***whenever*** it works best for you!

Comment: Your answer is a very good and satisfactory one. Just one question: What do you mean by PT?

Comment: PT = Physical Therapist see http://www.apta.org/AboutPTs/

Comment: OK, OK, I understood. :-)